# WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty not changing max peers

Tags: c++, wlanapi

So I came across a problem when calling WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty from WLanapi.dll. This is that the dwMaxNumberOfPeers from WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_CONNECTION_SETTINGS passed into that function is not going to be persisted unless SSID is different to the previous call.

Scenario 1 (problem):

1. I call **WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty** and pass **WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_CONNECTION_SETTINGS** with **dwMaxNumberOfPeers** 5, and **SSID** "MyNetwork"
2. When I call **WlanHostedNetworkQueryProperty** I get the details I have just set
3. Now I call **WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty** again, this time **dwMaxNumberOfPeers** is 10, and **SSID** stays "MyNetwork"
4. When I call **WlanHostedNetworkQueryProperty** I will get **dwMaxNumberOfPeers** 5, not 10...

Scenario 2 (no problem):

1. I call **WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty** and pass **WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_CONNECTION_SETTINGS** with **dwMaxNumberOfPeers** 5, and **SSID** "MyNetwork"
2. When I call **WlanHostedNetworkQueryProperty** I get the details I have just set
3. Now I call **WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty** again, this time **dwMaxNumberOfPeers** is 10, and **SSID** is changed "MyOtherNetwork"
4. When I call **WlanHostedNetworkQueryProperty** I will get **dwMaxNumberOfPeers** correctly set to 10...

Has any of you come across that? How did you solve it without setting some fake random SSID every time I want to change max peers of the hosted network?